# How do i cast char to integer while querying in django ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

Recently started using Django ORM.I want to execute this query

```
 select student_id from students where student_id like "%97318%" order by CAST(student_id as UNSIGNED) desc;
```

where student_id is a CharField which I want as integer for querying.
I tried with

```
  students.objects.filter(student_id__contains "97318").order('-student_id')
```

works fine. But don't know and couldn't find how to cast "student_id" to int like the actual MySQL query mentioned above with "Django ORM". should I use raw query or is there a way out?
Let me know your suggestions.

Comment: You're missing `=` on the `filter(...)`. If raw query works for you, I wonder is there any special reason you *have to* use ORM?

Comment: @Anzel  You can't order strings by their number values.  `"2" > "11"` but `2 < 11`

Comment: @catavaran, I agreed, but still doesn't explain why this *has to* be in ORM, whereas raw sql can perform just fine

Comment: @Anzel raw sql is not required here. `extra()` can do the job just fine.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

An updated alternative without requiring the use of `extra` is the cast function (new in Django 1.10):

```
>>> from django.db.models import FloatField
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Cast
>>> Value.objects.create(integer=4)
>>> value = Value.objects.annotate(as_float=Cast('integer', FloatField())).get()> 
>>> print(value.as_float)
4.0
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast

Comment: This seems to be latest working solution, hence accepting it:)

Answer (score 13):

Use queryset's [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method:

```
students.objects.filter(student_id__contains="97318") \
                .extra({'stident_id_uint': "CAST(student_id as UNSIGNED)"}) \
                .order_by('-student_id_uint')
```

Comment: Since Django 1.11 extra is marked as deprecated, so be wary of using it

Answer (score 9):

I have tried `extra()` and `annotate()` to `CAST`, but they did not work well with related fields and generates JOINS resulting unexpected queryset sometimes.

What I ended up was to create a Custom Lookup.

The documentation is few but can be found at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/#custom-lookups) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/lookups/#django.db.models.Transform)

Here is my example:

```
@Field.register_lookup
class IntegerValue(Transform):
    # Register this before you filter things, for example in models.py
    lookup_name = 'int'  # Used as object.filter(LeftField__int__gte, "777")
    bilateral = True  # To cast both left and right

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        sql, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        sql = 'CAST(%s AS UNSIGNED)' % sql
        return sql, params
```

Then below should work:

```
students.objects.filter(student_id__int__gte="97318").order('-student_id')
```

Comment: where to put this lookup file?

Answer (score 2):

Use [cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) from Django.
If you are working with Django CBV (class based view) you can do this way:

models.py:

```
class Document(TenantAwareModel):
    document_data = JSONField(null=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

def get_queryset(self):
    document = Document.objects.annotate(document_data_as_text=Cast('document_data', TextField()))
    user = self.request.user
    tenant = self.request.user.tenant
    return document.filter(tenant=tenant)
```

Then, in your method you can use **document_data_as_text** as a normal field to filter by it:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    document_part_filter_param = request.query_params.get("documentPart")
    if document_part_filter_param:
        queryset = queryset.filter(document_data_as_text__unaccent__icontains=document_part_filter_param)
```