# __contains not working for numbers? (Django + MongoDB)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoose, django-queryset

I have some inputs of **type="text"** in a table in my template code (html). When clicking "Search", I collect the values from the inputs like this:

```
$(".filterInput").each(function() {
    var column_name = $(this).attr("name")
    filters[column_name] = $(this).val();
});
```

So, filters is a json object which contains all the filters I want to apply.

Afterwards, I call a view with an ajax call and I send the variable filters to it. There, I transform the filters variable into an object called query, which has the __contains parameter. I do it with the following code (python):

```
query = {}
for k, v in filters.items():
    if v:
        query[k + '__icontains'] = v
```

And then I call MongoDB like this:

```
result = model.objects.filter(**query).order_by(order_by).skip(page_size*(page-1)).limit(page_size).only(*attr_names)
```

For some reason, for the string parameters in my MongoDB, it works fine. I can find for '**ca**' and it will find things like '**Ca**lamity' or 'al**ca**line'. However, if I look for **2** in a numeric field, it will only get results that are exactly **2**, but not 7**2** or **2**34. If I look for **234** I will get results with **234** but not 5**234**6 or **234**56

Why is it? Might it be related to the fact that I'm comparing text with numbers? How can I fix that? And why does it work for the exactly-matching records?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i cast char to integer while querying in django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101580/how-do-i-cast-char-to-integer-while-querying-in-django-orm)

Comment: Not really. They talk about extra(), but django is about to deprecate it. They also mention annotate(), but I don't know how to make it work dynamically.