# Search by contents of integer field in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a table containing a list of phone prefixes, stored as integers.
However I want to be able to search in those in a 'contains' way, so e.g. when searching for '32' I would like to see all records that contain the actual text '32' in the prefix.

That is no problem if using plain SQL of course, but I can't find any guidance on how to accomplish this in Django.

Basically the part that matters is now:

```
if search_value:
    destinations = destinations.filter(description__icontains=search_value)
```

And it would have to be something like:

```
if search_value:
    destinations = destinations.filter(description__icontains=search_value, prefix__icontains=search_value)
```

However, since 'prefix' is an integer column, this does not yield any results.

What is the best approach for this? I was thinking of a generated field in MySQL, but then again I don't know how to make that field available in the Django model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is to CAST the prefix field as a CHAR and then filter against the CAST version of the field.

Take a look at this stackoverflow question:

[How do i cast char to integer while querying in django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101580/how-do-i-cast-char-to-integer-while-querying-in-django-orm)

Comment: Django's [extra function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra) is exactly what I need indeed!