# operator does not exist: character varying + character varying

Tags: python, django, postgresql, casting, average

I changed the db from sqlite to postgresql for production for my website and I'm getting this error. It didn't get this error when i was working locally with sqlite. Using Django.

```
ProgrammingError at /boards/1/companies/1/

operator does not exist: character varying + character varying
LINE 1: ...Col1, (AVG(((("boards_review"."move_in_condition" + "boards_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://www.flythecoop.io/boards/1/companies/1/
Django Version:     2.2.6
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

operator does not exist: character varying + character varying
LINE 1: ...Col1, (AVG(((("boards_review"."move_in_condition" + "boards_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Exception Location:     /home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 84
Python Executable:  /home/reviews/venv/bin/python3.8
Python Version:     3.8.0
Python Path:    

['/home/reviews/venv/bin',
 '/home/reviews/reviews',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python38.zip',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 24 Nov 2019 05:52:27 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /home/reviews/reviews/templates/baseb.html, error at line 0
operator does not exist: character varying + character varying LINE 1: ...Col1, (AVG(((("boards_review"."move_in_condition" + "boards_... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Looking at the error, it said something about the snippet of code (AVG(((.........
What the Avg does is it shows average ratings for all reviews of a company.
each of the strings such as "move_in_condition" all have integer values.
The only place I have that is in my models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    #bio = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='companies')
    starter = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='companies',
    )
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_avg(self):
        return self.reviews.annotate(
            overall_rating = Avg(
                F('move_in_condition') + 
                F('treatment') + 
                F('response_speed') +
                F('maintenance_quality')
            )/4).aggregate(
                Avg('overall_rating'), 
                Avg('move_in_condition'),
                Avg('treatment'),
                Avg('response_speed'),
                Avg('maintenance_quality')
            )
```

Looking at other responses, it looks like I have to add explicit typecasts, but i'm not sure how to implement, or should i just get rid of the "+" somehow altogether?

Edit - Updated to use integerfield if thats a better way, but still have same issue. Including my fields below:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    STAY = (
        ('less than 6 months', 'less than 6 months'),
        ('6 months', '6 months'),
        ('10 months', '10 months'),
        ('12 months', '12 months'),
        ('More than 1 year', 'More than 1 year'),
    )
    YES_NO = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )
    SECURITY = (
        ('100%', '100%'),
        ('75%', '75%'),
        ('50%', '50%'),
        ('25%', '25%'),
        ('0%', '0%'),
        ('Still waiting', 'Still waiting'),
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default="")
    length_of_stay = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STAY, blank=False, default='None')

    move_in_condition = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default='5')
    #Landlord Interaction
    treatment = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default ="5")
    response_speed = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default ="5")
    maintenance_quality = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default ="5")    

    security_deposit_returned = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SECURITY, blank=False, default ="None")
    #put text "ignore if still waiting"
    is_this_a_fair_amount = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=YES_NO, blank=False, default="1")
    would_you_recommend = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=YES_NO, blank=False, default="1")
    additional_comments = models.TextField(max_length=4000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

Comment: It seems like that column should have a numeric type instead of varchar if you are intending to do math operations on it.  You could cast it whenever you intend to use it, but that's extra work, slow, and prone to errors.

Comment: I edited to use IntegerField instead of Charfields - updated the question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Did that change the type of the column in the database?  If they are still stored as varchar instead of integers, it won't fix the issue.

Comment: tried it but didn't work. i read sql doesn't directly support changing a string column to an int column so maybe that explains it? I've tried deleting the db altogether and starting a new one, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried, but it does work: `create table test (a varchar); alter table test alter column a type int USING a::int;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres uses different (ANSI/SQL) symbols for [string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) concat operation. You should to use `||` instead `+`. Same operators like Postgres has Oracle.

```
postgres=# SELECT varchar 'AHOJ' + varchar 'AHOJ';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying + character varying
LINE 1: SELECT varchar 'AHOJ' + varchar 'AHOJ';
                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
postgres=# SELECT varchar 'AHOJ' || varchar 'AHOJ';
+----------+
| ?column? |
+----------+
| AHOJAHOJ |
+----------+
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I think I might have not given enough detail in my questions. the strings that i'm adding such as  F('move_in_condition') + ...... and all the others all have integer values. each has a value 1-5. I'm not sure if the || will work as i'm not exactly looking to   concat strings but doing math with the values of the strings. If that helps to better understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Lighthouse - then you have to do cast to int first. But I don't know how to do it in Django. I found some examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101580/how-do-i-cast-char-to-integer-while-querying-in-django-orm