# Django ORM - Cast and filter a queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

I would like to cast a related column to integer and then filter a queryset, but I can not get it to work. These are my models

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...


class MetricType(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Metrics(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="metrics")
    metric_type = models.ForeignKey(MetricType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

For simplicity, let's suppose I have the following data. (This example is an oversimplification, but the problem is the same).

```
Author:
 - Name: Miguel de Cervantes
 - Name: William Shakespeare

Book:
 - Title: Don Quixote, Author: Miguel de Cervantes
 - Title: Hamlet, Author: William Shakespeare

MetricType:
 - Label: Pages

Metrics:
  - Book: Don Quixote, MetricType: Pages, value: 100
  - Book: Hamlet, MetricType: Pages, value: 40
```

Now, the only thing I want to do is get all the books that have more than N pages. This would be really easy to do in normal circumstances but in this case I need to cast the value of the metrics and then do the filter. I have tried the following:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from . import models

value = 50

pages_metric = models.MetricType.objects.get(label='Pages')

models.Book.objects.annotate(
    pages=Cast('metrics__value', IntegerField()
).filter(
    metrics__metric_type=pages_metric, pages__gte=value
)
```

I'd like to get one book, the one that have 100 pages, but I get this nasty error instead:

```
(1055, "Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'XXXXX' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")
```

**I have no access to modify my MySQL server settings and I can not modify the database schema for now since this is a legacy database**. Is there anything I can do in Django to make this work?

Comment: Why not to store value as Integer initially?

Comment: It is a legacy database with legacy code. It is out to my control for now.

Comment: Have you tried this -> http://www.programmersought.com/article/73391843184/

Comment: @Dalvtor you may want to edit your question to make clear that it's a legacy db and you cannot change the schema - because my first reaction too was to write "get rid of this 'metrics' thing and just store the pages count (as int) as part of the book" ;-)

Comment: Yep, that would make things easier :D. I will edit the question

Comment: @Dalvtor thanks ;-) - FWIW, in the worst case (or if you're in a hurry to deliver but can come back to it later), Django's ORM let you use plain SQL queries too. Not necessarily the "cleanest" solution but still quite useful when your query becomes too complex  for the ORM or when your legacy schema doesn't match some of the ORM's limitations. Remember that this ORM has been designed as a "80/20" solution - makes things as simple as possible for the most common use cases (80%) while still being able to handle the remaining corner cases (20%) even if less elegantly.

Comment: @Dalvtor Maybe this can help, seems others have had unexpected queries occurring when casting values and also carrying out joins based on those casts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101580/how-do-i-cast-char-to-integer-while-querying-in-django-orm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i cast char to integer while querying in django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101580/how-do-i-cast-char-to-integer-while-querying-in-django-orm)